# Getting connection refused IO exception for localSocketConnection

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi, wifi

I am trying to create a unix domain socket at local to wlan0 ( WIFI )  interface in an Android application by consuming the API's provided by Android SDK for [Creating local socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket.html)

Below is my code

```
      try {
            LocalSocket mSocket=new LocalSocket();
            LocalSocketAddress address=new LocalSocketAddress("wlan0",LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.ABSTRACT);
            mSocket.connect(address);

        } catch (  IOException ex) {
            Log.d("exception raised ", Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        }
```

Below is the stacktrace of the exception from logs

```
10-27 17:17:08.465    3212-3212/com.test.sockettest D/exception raised﹕ java.io.IOException: Connection refused
            at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
            at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:258)
            at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:108)
            at com.globaledgesoft.sockettest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody please help me understand why I am getting this exception, I am actually having the permission. Below is my manifest permission string.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

I am new to this Android Socket programming,

Thanks in advance for the help